# push data using a batch API

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a working pipeline and need to write data to my target system which provides a "batch web service" i.e., I can only post a csv file attachment and cannot post one transaction at a time.  I have a two step process now - my pipeline first writes results of the transformation to cloud storage using TextIO,  then another program extracts the file and invokes the batch API to push data to the target system.

How I can make this a single step process given I first need to prepare csv data before invoking the batch API?  Is it possible to extend TextIO to not just finalize the file but also call the API before finishing?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds exactly like a job for a [user-defined sink](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/sources-and-sinks#creating-sinks)! In particular, for a FileBasedSink. Your Writer would write records to files, while your WriteOperation's finalize method would push the final files to the batch API.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the XmlSink sample just to get my feet wet with custom sinks.  It created individual xml files per bundle, however for some reason the _finalize()_ method is never invoked.  Here's my pipeline code.  Any ideas?  `XmlSink.Bound myBoundedXmlSink = XmlSink.writeOf(AdFrequency.class, "ads", "gs://springml-bucket1/myxml/ad_output_file");
p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.from(options.getInput()))
  .apply(new TotalClickCount())  
  .apply(com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Write.to(myBoundedXmlSink));`

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Can you detail how you detected that finalize() was not invoked on your sink - do you mean that the final output never appeared and temporary files were left over in their temporary location?

Comment: Yes, that's how I figured that finalize() was not called.  The temporary files are left over and a final output file never got created.

Comment: Sounds like a serious bug and we would appreciate your help in isolating it. Could you please follow up with some more details (e.g. a job ID, some more of the code of your pipeline, any peculiar details about the buckets you use) to dataflow-feedback@google.com ?

Comment: XmlSink produces an output file for each bundle the Dataflow service distributes your records over. The finalize() method of FileBasedSink does not merge these output files (though a custom sink could override finalize() to provide this behavior), but instead renames them according to a bundle naming scheme.  This was the behavior that was observed and the system was working as intended.